# How convert this SQL query to linq?

Tags: sql, linq

I have this SQL query and I want to convert it to linq:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN AsiDurumu = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / MAX(CovidId) 
FROM Covids
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Do you know that `GroupBy(x => 1)` by constant will give you ability to use two aggregates in one expression?

Comment: i can't try because its so hard for me so i wrote on stackoverflow

Comment: A good start would be to find an O/R mapper that supports LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need several aggregation expressions in one non-grouping LINQ Query, you should GroupBy by constant. EF has special translation for such cases.

```cs
var query = 
    from c in ctx.Covids
    group c by 1 into g
    select new 
    {
        Some = g.Sum(x => x.AsiDurumu == "1" ? 1 : 0) / g.Max(x => x.CovidId)
    };
```

Comment: i get an error in x.AsiDurumu, Cannot implicitly convert type to 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: That's cool. Which one? Use google translate if you cannot express your thoughts

Comment: (x.AsiDurumu ? 1 : 0) name of the error is Cannot implicitly convert type to 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: Corrected answer. That's because you forgot to post your model. Anyway everything is under common sense and you can fix that by yourself.

Comment: can you look this my problem ? please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479655/convert-this-sql-query-to-an-equivalent-linq-query