# when i started the program i get error from query

Tags: asp.net, linq

Hi i develop web app with c# and swagger. i have problem. why i took this exception ?

```
public AsiCovidDto GetAsiCovid()
{
    using(SirketDBContext context=new SirketDBContext())
    {
        var query = 
            from c in context.Covids
            group c by 1 into g
            select new AsiCovidDto
            {
                AsiCovidOrani = g.Sum(x => x.AsiDurumu == "1" ? 1 : 0) / g.Max(x => x.CovidId)

            };
        //exception  return (AsiCovidDto)query;
    }
}
```

exception

[image]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: What the point of `group c by 1` ?

Comment: GroupBy(x => 1) by constant will give you ability to use two aggregates in one expression

Comment: Next time, please use tags to indicate which ORM you're using and which version. I assume some Entity Framework version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you just have the result object (an `IQueryable<T>`), as your exception states.

This doesnt provide a cast as to the desired type.
What you need to do is to extract your object from `IQueryable<T>` via
`query.First()`

Comment: Better `First()`, this query always return one record.

Comment: If it contains data or not it will return one record. Always. It is like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table` - always returns one record to show how many records.

Comment: ok changed it ^^

Comment: unfortunately returns 0 in swagger. i didn't expect this. i wonder my linq is wrong?

Comment: Probably because you divide integers, also strange that you divide by Max Id.

Comment: i asked and i got this linq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422643/how-convert-this-sql-query-to-linq/70424797?noredirect=1#comment124490874_70424797

Comment: You`ve got what you have asked. Cast to  `(double)g.Max(x => x.CovidId)` and try again.

Comment: you are definitly my hero. thank you @SvyatoslavDanyliv